# Colon sign(:) causes issue with Python 3.4 & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, syntax-error, ubuntu-14.04

My Python code is successfully working with Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04. However, it gives  the following syntax error when I moved to the Ubuntu 14.04& Python 3.4:

```
        line 123
        self.__last_packet: Packet = None
                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Did something changed between Python3.4 and  3.6? I also want to know the meaning of the colon(:) operator for such a case. I added 'if' at the front of the problematic line, and seems that syntax issue was solved, but I don't think that author of the code meant an 'if' statement there.

By the way, the line was taken from the constructor part of a Python class.

Comment: It's hard to tell what may have gone wrong without looking at the code and the Full Traceback error.

Comment: Note, the colon is not an operator, it is part of the type-hinting syntax, which didn't exist until 3.5

Answer (score 2):

Type hinting come up with Python 3.5 (please see [Python 3.5 changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html)).
So, yes you have to remove the `: Packet` stuff.

Comment: or just upgrade to at least python 3.5 ;)